# Makefile targets using different sources

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to have different source files build and linked into a binary by adding sources inside the targets:

```
...

C_SOURCE_FILES  = common_file_1.c
C_SOURCE_FILES += common_file_2.c

target_1: C_SOURCE_FILES += target_1_specific_file.c
target_1: all

target_2: C_SOURCE_FILES += target_2_specific_file.c
target_2: all

C_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES = $(notdir $(C_SOURCE_FILES))
C_PATHS = $(call remduplicates, $(dir $(C_SOURCE_FILES) ) )
OBJECTS = $(addprefix _build/, $(C_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES:.c=.o) )

all:
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) -o _build/output_file.out

_build/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC_PATHS) -c -o $@ $<
```

But for some reason target-specific files never get built, even though I launch make this way: `make target_1`.

EDIT:

Added definition of `OBJECTS`.

Comment: Where is `$(OBJECTS)` defined in the `makefile` ?

Comment: You never use the `C_SOURCE_FILES` variable for anything.  Basically, the makefile you've provided is missing lots of important information for us to help you.  However, I'll say up front what the problem most likely is: if you check the docs you'll see that target-specific variables CANNOT be used in prerequisite lists.  So, you cannot add different prerequisites for a target based on the value of target-specific variables.

Comment: Sorry, I've added the definition for the `OBJECTS` variable. How should targets consisting of different source files be built using makefile if not by modifying prerequisite lists?